# Change default behavior of ENTER in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am using a bar code scanner to scan a QR code and enter data into the cells. After inserting the data, the behavior is click of ENTER key. This takes the current cell to the cell below it. But I want to change this behavior. I want it to move to the next cell in the same row. Is it possible under these conditions?:-

1. Using Google Sheets on mobile phone
2. Without using Google App Script or macros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution to this strictly lies outside Google Sheets: change the settings of your scanner to insert a tab rather than a carriage return after each barcode.